# Atelier B - Proof obligations of "H => vv$1 = vv$2" format for vv used in WHILE substitution

Tags: formal-verification, formal-methods, b-method

I am trying to understand Proof Obligations of this format:
`H => vv$1 = vv$2`
vv is a var used in an implementation within a WHILE substitution.
What does this PO mean and how to prove it?
Thanks

Here is the structure of the B project:

- machines head, utils, main
- implementations: main_i

The code is the following:

**head.mch**

```
MACHINE
    head

SETS
    ELEMENTS = {element0,element1,element2}

END
```

**utils.mch**

```
MACHINE
    utils

SEES
    head
    
OPERATIONS
      xx <-- addElement (el) = 
         PRE
             el : ELEMENTS &
             el /= element0 &
             xx : seq(ELEMENTS)
         THEN
            xx := xx <- el    
         END
 END
```

**main.mch**

```
MACHINE
    main

SEES
    head
    
VARIABLES
    vv, INIT

INVARIANT
    vv : seq(ELEMENTS) & INIT : BOOL    

INITIALISATION
  vv := [] || INIT := TRUE 

OPERATIONS         
    Op1 (pp) = 
        PRE
             pp : seq(ELEMENTS) &
             size(pp) > 0 &            
             INIT = TRUE &
             !xx.(xx: dom(pp) => pp(xx) /= element0)
         THEN
             INIT := FALSE 
         END

END
```

**main.imp**

```
IMPLEMENTATION main_i
REFINES main

SEES
    head
    
IMPORTS
    utils
    
CONCRETE_VARIABLES
    vv, INIT

INVARIANT
    vv : seq(ELEMENTS) & INIT : BOOL    

INITIALISATION
  vv := [];
  INIT := TRUE 

OPERATIONS         
    Op1(pp) = 
        ASSERT
             pp : seq(ELEMENTS) &
             size(pp) > 0 &            
             INIT = TRUE &
             !xx.(xx: dom(pp) => pp(xx) /= element0)
         THEN
             VAR ii IN
                    ii := 1;  
                    WHILE 
                        ii <= size(pp) & ii : dom(pp)  
                    DO
                       vv <-- addElement(pp(ii));
                       ii := ii + 1                           
                   INVARIANT
                      ii : NATURAL1 & ii <= size(pp)+1 & vv: seq(ELEMENTS)           
                   VARIANT
                      size(pp)-ii+1                 
                   END
              END;
              INIT := FALSE
         END
END
```

Comment: Could you provide the code from which the PO has been generated?

P.S. Note that the Help has a "Proof Obligations Reference" that may help answering the first question.

Comment: I added the code of the project to the body of the question

Comment: Also, invariant like `INIT = FALSE => size(vv)>0` in the main_i generates a blocking PO. How to tackle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vv$1` is the value of state variable `vv` after the operation `Op1` completes, according to the specification/machine. In the specification, this state variable is unchanged.

`vv$2` is the value of state variable `vv` after the operation `Op1` completes, according to the implementation. In the implementation, this state variable is updated.

For the implementation to be a correct refinement, `vv$1` and `vv$2`  must always be equal. Yet they are not, and the provided implementation is not a correct refinement. So the proof obligation is not valid.

Some additional pieces of advice:

- In machine `utils`, operation `addElement` shall distinguish the value of the sequence before and after :

```
      after <-- addElement (before, el) = 
         PRE
             el : ELEMENTS &
             el /= element0 &
             before : seq(ELEMENTS)
         THEN
            after := before <- el    
         END
```

- Avoid identifier `pp`, as it is also the name of a command in the interactive prover.

Comment: Thanks! looks like adding `vv ::seq(ELEMENTS)` in the specification solves it indeed.

Comment: What about adding an invariant like `INIT = FALSE => size(vv)>0` in the main_i? Seems to generate a blocking PO.

Comment: Sorry if I sound pedantic, but I think that the rationale of stackoverflow is to have one entry per question and you are asking a different question. And there is a limit on the size of the reply that I reach when I try to answer :)

Comment: Ok will put this in a new question.
One remark just to be sure, is the vv$2 actually related to the state of vv within the loop, or after the operation Op1 in implementation completes?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd say option 2.